# Odds for multiple lottery tickets

Tags: probability

If the overall odds of a winning lottery game are $1/X$.   What are the odds of winning when you buy $Y$ tickets where $Y \ge X$.  I mean the combined chances that any of the $Y$ tickets win?

I'm confused because I think that probability can never be greater than 1 (or absolute certainty) but my incorrect understanding of the formula renders answers greater than 1 out of 1.

Comment: The probability of winning buying 2 tickets is not the sum of the probability for one ticket. You can sum the probability of events when they are disjoint from the *same probability space*. That's a common misunderstanding. If two variables are independent you don't sum the probability. For example what are the odds that it rains or that you win the lottery? You won't sum the probabilities right? Instead you could look at the probability that you dont win the lottery and it does not rain. In this case you can multiply the probability.

Comment: Independent events: you want to work with intersection. Disjoints event from the same probability space you want to work with union.

Comment: 1/X, I think the total number of tickets would be X.( my naive assumption)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you do not choose the lottery ticket numbers - if you could, then buy all the possibilities and guarantee a win

Then making assumptions about independence and uniform probabilities, you might consider the chance that all your lottery tickets lose, coming to a final  answer like $$1-\left(1-\frac{1}{X}\right)^Y$$ which is about $1-e^{-Y/X}$ for large $X$ and larger $Y$

Comment: Why should you need larger $Y$?  That approximation is pretty accurate for even modest values of $Y$, provided $X$ is large enough, isn't it?

Comment: I saw a lotto game with over-all odds of 1 in 7 and thought what if I bought 10 tickets? A sufficiently simple minded person would have a "feeling" or "would seem like" they must win.  I wanted to see the formula and make the calculation- Thanks Henry!

Comment: @BrianTung $Y \ge X$ was in the question

Comment: @Henry: Ahh, OK, I thought you were saying that you needed $Y \geq X$ for a good approximation.